# Dealing with the separator in CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to compile some Java code with CMake (I'm aware that Java is not really the use-case for CMake) and I want to provide the class paths for the files. The compilation should work on both Unix and Windows systems. The problem I have is with separating the different class paths. Using:

```
set(CLASS_PATH ${PATH1} ${PATH2})
message(STATUS "${CLASS_PATH}")
```

prints

```
<PATH1>;<PATH2>
```

But this happens on both Unix and Windows. So I have to manually add separators. The way I'm doing it is

```
if(${CMAKE_HOST_WIN32})
    set(SEP "\;")
elseif(${CMAKE_HOST_UNIX})
    set(SEP ":")
endif(${CMAKE_HOST_WIN32})
```

Is this really the best way to deal with separators? I feel like I'm missing something.

**Update - MCVE**

To describe my thought: `FILE_LIST` would be contain all the java files that I want to compile. I defined a custom function which I can call on this `FILE_LIST` and compile the files. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the function parameters?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)


set(CLASS_PATH E:/tmp/cmake/separator C:/tmp/)

set(FILE_LIST 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt)

add_custom_target(war ALL)

function(compile_java clp)
    foreach(java_file ${ARGN})
        add_custom_command(
            TARGET war
            PRE_BUILD
            COMMAND echo "${clp}" ${java_file}
        )
    endforeach(java_file)
endfunction()


compile_java("${CLASS_PATH}" ${FILE_LIST}) # I have to pass CLASS_PATH in quotes
```

Comment: `;` is CMake's sperator for items in a list. In many places, it's correctly translated to the native thing upon use (if you're using it in a place CMake understands). Can you show a [mcve] of what you're doing with your `CLASS_PATH` variable?

Comment: @Angew That's what I kind of thought, that CMake should handle the separator itself. I added an MCVE which should show my problem.

Comment: BTW, have you looked at CMake's [`UseJava` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/UseJava.html)?

Comment: I did. I just wasn't sure that it doesn't do too much (generating jar files directly instead of single class files). The thing is is, in a following step we compile these class files with GWT. But I think I can also do this from jar files. At least I will try it.

Comment: And what is the problem with your current `compile_java` function? It's not clear from the Q.

Comment: The problem is that when compile java executes the command and inserts the class path from the variable, they are still being separated by a semicolon and not the colon. So this translation mechanism regarding separators doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173399/discussion-between-angew-and-philipp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on comments, you want the path list as a single command-line argument, with a platform-specific separator. You can achieve this using string operations:

```
function(compile_java clp)
    if(NOT CMAKE_HOST_WIN32)
        string(REPLACE ";" ":" clp "${clp}")
    endif()
    foreach(java_file ${ARGN})
        add_custom_command(
            TARGET war
            PRE_BUILD
            COMMAND echo "${clp}" ${java_file}
        )
    endforeach(java_file)
endfunction()
```

Comment: Perfect, much simpler than my solution. Thanks